# How do I pass constructor arguments with dependency injection using Castle.Windsor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, subsonic, subsonic3, castle-windsor

I am wiring up my first SubSonic 3 application (in an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 front-end) and am looking at Rob's SimpleRepository.  I'm using Castle.Windsor as an injection framework.

In my application startup, I configure Castle to bind a SubSonic SimpleRepository to a SubSonic IRepository.  Nothing complicated there.  However, the SimpleRepository has a ctor overload which takes two values: a connection string name and a set of SimpleRepositoryOptions.  Not having dug too deep into Castle in the past, it's not clear if there is a way to specify the ctor arguments via configuration (or some other means).

Right now, I have a custom implementation of the SimpleRepository that explicitly creates a SimpleRepository with those arguments in it's parameterless ctor, but if I want to change these at any point in time, it requires changing the code and recompiling.

Is there a more elegant way to configure Castle to take constructor arguments?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this wiki page](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/inline-dependencies.md). What's called "parameters" on that page is either a constructor parameter (which is a required parameter) or a property (optional parameter)

Comment: That link is dead, and I couldn't find where it moved to - it seems they have some site errors right now.  It'd be more helpful if you included a working example or a pertinent excerpt.

Comment: @mskfisher : things change over the years. Updated link.

Comment: Thanks for updating the link.  Could you also add an example in case the link dies again in the future?

Answer (score 5):

If you're configuring Windsor using an XML file, you define your ctor arguments and their values like this:

```
<component id="repository" service="IRepository" type="SimpleRepository" ...>
    <parameters>
        <connectionString>your connection string</connectionString>
        ...
    </parameters>
</component>
```

See the Windsor configuration reference for more info:

http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v1rc3/manual/windsorconfigref.html

Comment: @mskfisher: XML registration is quite outdated.